# Google DoubleClick - Dynamic creative - refreshing data

Tags: double-click, double-click-advertising, google-web-designer

I have a Google DoubleClick account and I have linked it up to a google sheet.

The problem I am  having is after updating the google sheet I dont see the copy updated in the advert.

[image]

I also don't know the difference between 'transformed content' and 'element' and if I need to transform after every change.

The doubleclick documentation is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the data in your feed here's what you can do:

**Process:**

*If your feed has already been published you will need to create a draft of the feed

[see picture - create draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pb9P.jpg)

Go To the Manage Data Step (#2) and you can Retransform your data source (this goes to your original source and refreshes the data)

[see picture - retransform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biTAV.jpg)

Once the Retransform has occurred you can republish the feed if it's already been published or go back to testing if not.

If you're using Google Web Deisgner you will probably need to relink your Schema if any columns or fields have changed.

**Why this is necessary:**

When you set up a sheet and provide it to the dynamic feed DoubleClick copies the data in your sheet and caches it on their ad servers. If you change something in the sheet it will not be reflected on their servers until you Retransform the sheet.

You really shouldn't need to mess around in the Transformed Content and Element tabs as far as I have run into.

If you need to add columns or remove columns from your sheet be aware that you will have to remove the feed, save and then add it again as new content to get them to show up.

***BE AWARE THAT REMOVING COLUMNS ON A PUBLISHED FEED WILL BREAK ADS THAT ARE ALREADY RUNNING - If you need to remove a column it's better to start a new feed IMO.***